# Trouble uploading binary files using JavaScript FileReader API

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dojo, filereader

New to javascript, having trouble figuring this out, help!

I am trying to use the Javascript FileReader API to read files to upload to a server. So far, it works great for text files.

When I try to upload binary files, such as image/.doc, the files seem to be corrupted, and do not open.

Using dojo on the client side, and java on the server side, with dwr to handle remote method calls. Code :

Using a html file input, so a user can select multiple files to upload at once :

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
```

And the javascript code  which reads the file content:

```
        uploadFiles: function(eve) {
        var fileContent = null;

        for(var i = 0; i < this.filesToBeUploaded.length; i++){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(fileToBeUploaded) {
                return function(e) {
                    fileContent = e.target.result;
                    // fileContent object contains the content of the read file
                };
            })(this.filesToBeUploaded[i]);

            reader.readAsBinaryString(this.filesToBeUploaded[i]);
        }            
    }
```

The **fileContent** object will be sent as a parameter to a java method, which will write the file.

```
    public boolean uploadFile(String fileName, String fileContent) {
    try {
        File file = new File("/home/user/files/" + fileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        logger.error("Error uploading files: ", ex);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("Error uploading files: ", ioe);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have read some answers suggesting the use of xhr and servlets to achieve this.

Is there a way to use FileReader, so that it can read files of any type (text, image, excel etc.) ?

I have tried using `reader.readAsBinaryString()` and `reader.readAsDataUrl()` (Decoded the base64 fileContent before writing to a file), but they did not seem to work.

PS : 
1. Also tried `reader.readAsArrayBuffer()`, the resultant `ArrayBuffer` object shows some `byteLength`, but no content, and when this is passed to the server, all I see is `{}`.

2. This bit of code is intended to work on only newer versions of browsers..

Comment: Sorry, I think I accidentally overwrote someone else's edits

Comment: Have you tried using typed array views to read from the array buffer? Since you are using java on the server, and need to write the bytes to a file, you should find 'Int8Array' interesting.

Check this out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: Also, looks like FileReader.readAsBinaryString is deprecated as per the 12 July 2012 Working Draft from the W3C. 


Source - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsBinaryString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks N.M! So, it looks like ArrayBuffer objects cannot be used directly, and a DataView must be created in order to use them. Below is what worked -

```
    uploadFiles: function(eve) {
    var fileContent = null;

    for(var i = 0; i < this.filesToBeUploaded.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(fileToBeUploaded) {
            return function(e) {
                fileContent = e.target.result;
                var int8View = new Int8Array(fileContent);
                // now int8View object has the content of the read file!
            };
        })(this.filesToBeUploaded[i]);

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.filesToBeUploaded[i]);
    }            
}
```

Refer N.M 's comments to the question for links to the relevant pages.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Answer (score 1):

example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                var sizef = document.getElementById('uploadImage').files[0].size;
                document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                document.getElementById("uploadImageValue").value = oFREvent.target.result; 
            };
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#viewSource').click(function ()
            {
                var imgUrl = $('#uploadImageValue').val();
                alert(imgUrl);

                //here ajax
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="uploadImageValue" name="uploadImageValue" value="" />
            <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /><br />
            <input id="uploadImage" style="width:120px" type="file" size="10" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif, image/png" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="viewSource">Source file</a>
    </body>
</html>
```